# Other Android resources

Tags: discussion

This site is great, and I like helping people, but keeping a laser-like focus means we have to turn people away.

Do you think it would be worthwhile to have a Community Wiki question with answers pointing to a variety of other resources? Here are the types of things I can think of off the top of my head:

- Developer resources
- Official sites
- Blogs
- Comparison sites
- Forums

What do you think?

Update: Considering [Jeff's Answer](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/269/other-android-resources/271#271), let's come up with a few resources that can fill these niches. Shopping comparison sites will be especially useful.

---

See: [Where can I ask questions that aren't Android Enthusiast questions?](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/371/where-can-i-ask-questions-that-arent-android-enthusiast-questions/)

Comment: XDA Forums is an excellent resource, especially for custom mods and the like.

Comment: Sure, but should we make such a question?

Comment: @Al if not a question, then perhaps a reference to other sites in the FAQ?

Comment: @Bryan: That would be fine with me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like a good idea, and reminds me of...

https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8401/where-can-i-ask-questions-that-arent-stack-overflow-questions

Which starts with

> Thank you for your confidence in our abilities! But have you read the Stack Overflow FAQ?
>
> We get a lot of IT/network/computer/technical questions on here, but Stack Overflow is meant to be first and foremost a programmer's resource.
>
> Yes, someone here might be able to help you, but you'll find that other forums more focused on your topic can give you a much better answer than a bunch of programmers. It's likely that your question will be downvoted, closed, and in some cases marked "offensive." It's not that we hate you, it's just that we're programmers and we like to keep our corn pops separate from our cocoa puffs.

I can see an android-flavored version of that getting plenty of traction.

Comment: I like it. I'll work on putting something together.

Answer (score 3):

I think we should.  We may not want to expand to Android dev questions and the like, but it would certainly be within the scope of the site to help Android Enthusiasts find resources when they want to get enthusiastic about modding/dev/etc.