# Where can I ask questions that aren't Android Enthusiast questions?

Tags: support, faq

**Thank you for your confidence in our abilities!** But have you read the [Android Enthusiasts FAQ](https://android.stackexchange.com/faq)?

This site is primarily a source to help people **use** their Android devices, whether it's an issue with hardware, software, a particular app, or even rooting. However, we get some other questions that don't fit here.

Yes, someone here might be able to help you, but you'll find that other forums and sites more focused on your topic can give you a much better answer than a bunch of Android geeks. It's likely that your question will be downvoted, closed, and in some cases marked "offensive." It's not that we hate you, it's just that we are trying to maintain the site's focus for maximum usability.

What forums can people go to to ask the questions that are off topic here? (Please list only **one** forum per answer so votes can bring the best forums to the top.)

Some potential topics might be:

- shopping recommendations
- phone hardware comparisons
- moderation support
- news blogs
- and so on

**Questions about programming issues with Android belong on [Stack Overflow](http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android).**

Comment: Can someone add: MDM/ Mobile Device Management & related Android issues to the question and Answers - most suitable places

Comment: @AlexS: This is a Community Wiki. You're invited to add/edit useful information yourself. I'm not sure exactly what it is you're requesting be done.

Comment: I tried, but couldn't do so. Maybe I don't yet have the privileges?

Answer (score 46):

### [XDA-developers](http://forum.xda-developers.com)

Large development community with plenty of space for users and devs alike to talk about anything Android.  Sub-forums for specific devices.  **Beware the trolls!**

- [App Development Forums](http://forum.xda-developers.com/forumdisplay.php?f=2188) (Development tools, marketing, monetization) This e.g. explicitly includes *Issues with the Android Market from the point of view of a developer or publisher* and *Marketing your Android app*, which are off-topic at Android Enthusiasts
- [Android Development and Hacking](http://forum.xda-developers.com/forumdisplay.php?f=564)
- Several device-specific development areas

Answer (score 41):

### [Our Chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/)

Anything Android related, really.

Comment: Assuming the user has enough reputation to join the chat room.

Answer (score 27):

## [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/)

For programming questions, including ones that just happen to be Android-related.

Answer (score 18):

### Reddit's Android Community

Links and discussions for all things Android.

- https://www.reddit.com/r/android
- https://www.reddit.com/r/androidapps
- https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev
- https://www.reddit.com/r/androidisawesome
- https://www.reddit.com/r/androidquestions
- https://www.reddit.com/r/androidthemes

Device-specific:

- https://www.reddit.com/r/nexusone
- https://www.reddit.com/r/htcevo
- https://www.reddit.com/r/Galaxy_S
- https://www.reddit.com/r/droid
- https://www.reddit.com/r/htcdesire

Private:

- https://www.reddit.com/r/androidappreviews

Comment: Especially [r/AndroidQuestions](http://www.reddit.com/r/AndroidQuestions/).

Answer (score 16):

### [Super User (Stack Exchange)](https://superuser.com/)

For questions about non-Android technology use.  For example, "What's required for a computer to be able to receive video over DLNA from my Android phone?" is really a question about computers, not Android, and should be on SuperUser.  If you have a DLNA card and appropriate PC software and can't get your phone to broadcast, however, Android Enthusiasts is a great place to ask a question about that.

Answer (score 15):

### [Google](http://www.google.com)

Sometimes a little Google-fu is all you need to solve your problem.

Answer (score 14):

### [Software Recommendations Stack Exchange](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/185)

This is one of our newer sister-sites, dedicated to software recommendations (aka "Is there an app for X?"). Please read the linked article before posting there to not have your question closed straight away, as it needs to meet certain criteria to be accepted.

Answer (score 10):

### [Anddev.org](http://www.anddev.org/)

Help with Android development and plenty of tutorials

Answer (score 9):

### [Android Developers Forums](http://developer.android.com/resources/community-groups.html)

List of different groups or forums for discussing development questions.

Answer (score 8):

### [Android Central](http://www.androidcentral.com/)

News blog and discussion forums. Here you can:

- check for [Android Accessories](http://forums.androidcentral.com/android-accessories/) (hint: Shopping recommendations seem to be on-topic here)
- participate in [Carrier Discussion](http://forums.androidcentral.com/carrier-discussion/)
- discuss [Android Developers](http://forums.androidcentral.com/android-developers/) issues

Answer (score 8):

### [IT Security Stack Exchange](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/android)

One of our very own Stack Exchange sites. It has quite a few questions tagged "[android](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/android)".

Answer (score 6):

### [Hardware Recommendations Stack Exchange](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/)

Similar to Software Recommendations, but for hardware.  Please note that they expect questions to be [specific and clear](https://hardwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/205/944) — you should read their [FAQ](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/asking) and [other guidance](https://hardwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/) before posting.

Answer (score 5):

### [Software Engineering Stack Exchange](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/android)

> Software Engineering Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for professionals, academics, and students working within the systems development life cycle. If you have a question about...
>
> - software development methods and practices
> - requirements, architecture, and design
> - quality assurance and testing
> - configuration management, build, release, and deployment
>
> ...then you're *probably* in the right place to ask your question.

Answer (score 4):

### [Droid Life](http://www.droid-life.com/about/)

Focused on the Droid family, but offers general Android news and information as well. Also reviews of apps and accessories.

Answer (score 4):

### [Phandroid](http://phandroid.com/)

News blog and podcast. See news for individual carriers, manufacturers, phones, or apps. Also [discussion forums](http://androidforums.com/):

- find [Android accessories](http://androidforums.com/android-accessories/) (shopping recommendations seem to be on-topic here)
- discussions on [Android Development](http://androidforums.com/android-development/)
- [Android Carriers](http://androidforums.com/android-carriers/) (mentioned in our FAQ as *Android-independent phone questions, such as "Does Carrier X have prepaid plans?"*)

Answer (score 3):

### [AndroidSPIN](http://androidspin.com/)

News, discussion, app finder, phones and accessories store. Discussion forums cover the following areas (among others):

- [Carriers](http://forum.androidspin.com/forumdisplay.php/1406-Carriers)
- [Android Customization and Development](http://forum.androidspin.com/forumdisplay.php/1404-Android-Customization-and-Development)
- [Android Software](http://forum.androidspin.com/forumdisplay.php/1401-Android-Software)
- several device-specific areas, including device-specific development
- [AndroidSPIN Marketplace](http://forum.androidspin.com/forumdisplay.php/1405-AndroidSPIN-Marketplace) to obtain/sell devices

Answer (score 3):

### [Droid Gamers](http://droidgamers.com/)

Android game reviews and news. Discussion forums.

Answer (score 3):

### [User Experience Stack Exchange](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/android)

A Stack Exchange site for issues regarding user experience and interface design. It has quite a few questions tagged "[android](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/android)".

Answer (score 3):

### [Android Police](http://www.androidpolice.com/)

Android news, app reviews, firmware updates, sharing tips, tricks, tutorials, videos and podcasts, device reviews, info about custom ROMs and hacks.

Answer (score 3):

### [GSM Arena](http://www.gsmarena.com/)

Android news, Android tech blog, device reviews, device tech specs and pictures, device estimated prices, device comparison, device rankings, device search based on user requested features, rumored devices.

Answer (score 3):

### [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/)

Another Stack Exchange site specific to Linux and Unix. They do say that [most question about Android are off-topic](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103/are-android-questions-on-topic) (because they belong either at StackOverflow, or Here) but if the questions actually relate to the "*nix" part of Android, they are on-topic. I have also seen quite a [few "compiling android" questions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/search?q=compile+android) there as well. So *Custom ROM Development* may be able to be asked there.

Answer (score 2):

### [Android and Me](http://androidandme.com/)

News blog.

Answer (score 2):

### [Android Community](http://androidcommunity.com/)

News blog, reviews, discussion forums, videos.

Answer (score 1):

### [Android Arena](http://www.androidarena.com/)

News blog.

Answer (score 1):

### [Android Tapp](http://www.androidtapp.com/)

App reviews, dev interviews, news.

Answer (score 1):

### [AndroidPIT](http://www.androidpit.com/)

News Blog, Forums (including device-specific and developer areas), App-Reviews, it even has its own [App Center](http://www.androidpit.de/de/android-market) where reviews are linked to the apps, and more.

- Development: [EN](http://www.androidpit.com/en/android/forum/category/1004000/Android-Developer-Forum) | [DE](http://www.androidpit.de/de/android/forum/category/4000/Android-Developer-Forum)
- Hardware search/shopping recommendations: [EN](http://www.androidpit.com/en/android/forum/category/1005020/) | [DE](http://www.androidpit.de/de/android/forum/category/2002927/)
- phone tariffs/data plans of different providers: [DE](http://www.androidpit.de/de/android/forum/category/2003257/Tarife-Forum)

Answer (score 1):

### [Android tag on Quora](https://www.quora.com/Android-OS)

You can ask anything Android related here. Unlike SE sites, subjective questions are welcomed here. Though you'll most likely get opinions, not solutions there.

Answer (score 1):

### [PhoneRocket](http://phonerocket.com/)

Not a discussion forum per se, the site offers comparisons of different smartphones.

> The site scores smartphones based on aggregated reviews, benchmarks, and specs. PhoneRocket also offers some common phone comparisons (Galaxy S4 vs. iPhone 5 and Galaxy S4 vs. HTC One, for example), and the ability to pit any two phones against each other.

Answer (score 1):

### [Android Authority](http://www.androidauthority.com/)

You can ask question on the [Q&A page](http://www.androidauthority.com/qa/ask)

**Other Features**:

Forum, Security, Development, Reviews, News, Interviews, Debates, Opinions etc

Answer (score 0):

#### [Reverse Engineering Stack Exchange](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/)

Our sister site for questions about reverse-engineering Android applications (APK). Please note that the community still expects the question to be clearly focus on the reverse-engineering part, rather than asking how to modify the app's behavior open-endedly.

Related tags: [android](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/android) [apk](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/apk).