# Where do I get good shopping recommendations?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where can I ask questions that aren't Android Enthusiast questions?](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/371/where-can-i-ask-questions-that-arent-android-enthusiast-questions)

As shopping recommendations are no good fit to questions on AE, where do I get help?

BTW: Arent't recommendations to apps also shopping recommendations, since they may cost some money?

Comment: Plain app recommendations are off-topic too -- money is irrelevant.  We do allow some as long as they can be rephrased as "How can I do X?" questions where the answer just happens to be "With App Y."