# Off-site resources off-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

One of our VTC-reasons reads:

> Questions asking us to **find or recommend an app, device, ROM, accessory or off-site resource** are off-topic for Android Enthusiasts as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam and become obsolete quickly. [Instead, describe your situation and the specific problem you're trying to solve.](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping)

Due to a [question asking for manuals](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/143470/16575) (which are not *explicitly* mentioned in this close-reason but most likely *implicated* by the term "off-site resource") I've checked for a corresponding post on Meta which I could refer the OP to to offer some background. Imagine my surprise when I didn't find any! I've checked our [help center](https://android.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and [FAQ](https://android.stackexchange.com/faq) immediately afterwards, but also nada.

As this is a "custom close reason" of our site, it didn't come "pre-installed" – so somehow it must have gotten there. Unless it came backpack on some malware and now always pops up in that list, we must have done something to bring it in there.

So my two-fold question is:

- What resource did I miss here were a community consensus was reached on this?
- If that cannot be found, should we now fill this gap to back the reason?

Don't get me wrong: I do ***not*** want to get rid of that close reason (it's there for a good reason: answers matching this formula tend to outdate quite soon, result in (rotting) link lists, and all the like).

#### Related Meta posts

- [Can the FAQ be expanded in terms of what's on topic?](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/q/589/16575)
- [Should the FAQ section on off-topic questions be clarified?](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/q/529/16575)
- [FAQ: “What kind of questions should I ask here?”](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/q/246/16575)
- [FAQ: “What kind of questions should I NOT ask here?”](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/q/247/16575)
- [“Where can I find a list/website/resource for X” questions](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/q/876/16575)

You will easily see all those are a bit older (post ID has only 3 digits, while we currently already reached 2146), so it might be time for a refresh anyway :)

Comment: Valid concern IMO

Comment: I originally tried to bring to light concerns with these types of questions [quite a while ago](http://meta.android.stackexchange.com/q/876/981). Beyond that, I think that we just ended up modelling the close reason after the one that Stack Overflow has, if I'm remembering right.

Comment: Good pointer, @eldarerathis (thanks for the link!) From the date of that post I see that was shortly before I've joined up – which explains why I don't remember it :)