# Where do I get buying recommendations for devices?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where can I ask questions that aren't Android Enthusiast questions?](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/371/where-can-i-ask-questions-that-arent-android-enthusiast-questions)

I know this site is not intended for buying recommendations, but where else could I get those from? I am curious on:

- Update / Upgrade policies of the vendor
- Speech quality
- Battery run times (under real conditions)
- GPS: accuracy and time-to-signal
- Network access time (time-to-use EDGE/GRPS/HSDPA/WiFi)
- WiFi power (Range)
- GUI responsiveness
- Rooting possible? (easy?)

When ever I discover a device, it is very tedious to check all those facts. And in the end I am disappointed again :).