# Can't add the "featured" tag to a question

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, tags, moderation

Not sure if this is a bug or I'm missing something, but I can't add [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) to [this question](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/371/where-can-i-ask-questions-that-arent-android-enthusiast-questions).

Comment: I deleted a tag and was then able to add it

Comment: For those who may be wondering, "featured" is a moderator-only tag and Matthew is a moderator. Non-Moderators can't attach that tag in any case.

Comment: Excuse my negligence, but what does the featured tag do?

Comment: @LiamW Just click the tag to see the wiki: http://meta.android.stackexchange.com/tags/featured/info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [looking on MSO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128531/the-moderator-tag-featured-must-be-present-but-it-wasnt-there-in-the-first#comment351216_128533) it appears that when [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) expires (after a week) the tag is removed from the cached render of the post but a new revision is not created.  So when you try to edit and add it, you're actually doing nothing, hence no change to the post.  To get around this you have to change the tags, as Bryan mentioned.

Still a bug.