# Can we get software recomendations added to on topic discussions?

Tags: discussion, scope, apps

I just got my question for a android web-server app marked as off topic. 
And I do see, that software recommendations are an [offence to this clause](https://android.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Ok, but why? I’m new to Android, and my ability to use, and utilize the OS is dependent on getting apps, which I can then use, and utilize to do things.

Since apps are a huge part of the Android experience, I’m not sure why asking for software recommendations is off topic. I am just now coming into the android community, and learning to use android. I do not know how to get everything I want to do done, but downloading apps is part of solving that problem.  I feel the basis of software recommendations has a significant level of potential usefulness for new users, and can be objectively rated using the Stack-Exchange formatted website.

I would like to note, in other OS specific Stack-Exchange communities, "software-recommendation" is an acceptable topic.

I beseech thee, gods of Android Enthusiast SE MODS, can we consider software-recommendations, as an on topic discussion?

Comment: Is there an issue with using http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: Only that I didnt know it existed. Thanks @MatthewRead, I will check that out!

Comment: Did you ask your question because of this question: [Are software recommendations on topic or not?](http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/14394)

Answer (score 6):

We wont, for multiple good reasons.

First, software recommendations are off-topic on many SE sites – with the definitive exception of one being dedicated to this, namely *Software Recommendations* (see: [Where to ask for app recommendations?](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2060/16575)).

Second, take a look at [What should our new off-topic close reasons be?](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1489/16575):

> Questions seeking application recommendations are off-topic as they become obsolete quickly.

Third, they very much tend to attract spam, link-only answers, and the like.

Comment: android is such a different ecosystem compared to 'general software' which could be Linux, Mac, Windows, iOS, etc...

Comment: “software recommendations are off-topic on all but one SE site” Where did you get this blatantly incorrect statement? For example [apple.se], [unix.se] and [ubuntu.se] allow software recommendation questions and have no wish to stop doing so.

Comment: @Gilles wasn't aware of those exceptions. Answer fixed up accordingly, thanks for pointing out so boldly ;)

Comment: @Izzy Is it really the case that software recommendations are off-topic on *most* sites? Or rather, yes, software recommendations are *off-topic* on most sites, because those sites aren't about software. But among the sites where software is on-topic, I'm not sure that a majority rejects software recommendation questions. Unless you count by traffic, then because SO doesn't like them and the other sites are negligible quantities.

Comment: @Gilles feel free to post your own answer. I wrote mine according to my experiences. And I frequently encountered this remark. I'll make another edit changing that to "many" (as you're correct: I'm not familiar with enough SE sites to give such a "big statement" – though I gave it mainly because I was told so in many cases, that there are only few exceptions).