# Where to ask for app recommendations?

Tags: discussion, faq-proposed, app-recommendation

I want to ask recommendations for apps for a given purpose, e.g., managing bank account information. I know my questions won't fit the main site. Where can I have more luck for these questions, within SE network or outside it (e.g., some subreddits at Reddit, some Android forums)?

Answer (score 37):

Within Stack Exchange network [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) is what you need. Its [help center](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) notes:

> This site is for questions asking for recommendations of software to accomplish a particular task, that is, “what software can I use to do …?”.

It further adds

> Good software recommendation requests have two components:
>
> - A purpose — a task to accomplish, a user story
> - Some objective requirements — a minimum set of features

**An asker there is supposed to follow the question quality guidelines** laid down at [What is required for a question to contain “enough information”?](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information) It will let you understand what appropriate information should your question **must** have. Unclear question or info deliberately held down by asker (due to uncertainty often) makes a question good candidate for closure and/or downvote and/or it may not receive other users' attention, let alone helpful suggestions as comments or answers.

In case of further queries, use their [Meta](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/). As expected, they also have an [official chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12851/software-recommendations) with at least one moderator or an experienced user often available there. They may prove to be helpful if clarification may be too less of a thing to ask on meta.

As for the sites outside the Stack Exchange network, the answers here may help: [Where can I ask questions that aren't Android Enthusiast questions?](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/q/371/96277)

Comment: That deserves multiple upvotes! One for mentioning the correct places, and at least one more for giving detailed background (especially concerning the quality guidelines on SR). Thanks a lot!