# Is it ok to ask for Android software recommendation on https://android.stackexchange.com?

Tags: discussion

Is it ok to ask for Android software recommendation on https://android.stackexchange.com ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where to ask for app recommendations?](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2060/where-to-ask-for-app-recommendations)

Answer (score 6):

As our [help pages explain](https://android.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic): **NO.** The off-topic section especially mentions:

> Questions asking the community to find or recommend something for you (a device, **app,** ROM, website, etc), including what to buy and where to buy it

(emphasis mine). Also see: [Where to ask for app recommendations?](//android.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2060/16575)

Comment: @iBug 1. look at the dates of this answer and the comment above. 2. this Q asks whether it's OT – the other asks for good places; so no duplicate in the literal sence to me. Feel free to throw your own vote :D

Comment: Yepp. So shall we cleanup the comments here? :)