# Can we ask for genuine reviews of an Android Phone here?

Tags: discussion, question-appropriateness, scope

Currently I am using Google's Android One device and I am about to purchase a new Smart phone soon. I was researching on the options available and noticed that some online retailers have fake reviewers and reviews too have become a part of marketing strategy.

As here on this site we have real Android enthusiasts **Can I ask for genuine reviews of Lenovo Vibe X2 and Huawei Honor 6 here ?**

I thought of before asking and getting the question closed, I should ask in meta first. IMHO it should be allowed as name of this site is **Android Enthusiasts** instead of **Android Programmers**.

Answer (score 8):

The Help Center page [What topics can I as about here?](https://android.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) has the following sections:

> - Recommendations, like "Which phone is better?" or "Can you suggest an app that does X?"
> - Shopping advice and suggestions, including what device to buy or where to buy it

This is because shopping questions have no one definite answer, and as such are a bad fit for a question/answer site. Each user has their own preferences and use patterns, and therefore the answers can't be really considered universal.

Therefore, in my opinion, your question is better suited on a forum instead of a q/a site. Maybe you'll find a suitable place listed in [Where can I as questions that aren't Android Enthusiasts questions?](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/371/where-can-i-ask-questions-that-arent-android-enthusiast-questions)

Comment: Thanks for the link.. I am not asking about the opinion of device.. I just wanted to know if someone has this device already what are their views and will they recommend it to someone else ?

Comment: @Amit it's far too open in that regard. I could say that the Galaxy S5 is the absolute best phone there is, and you'll spend a fortune on one and find it tacky and plastic and bloated. What I like in a phone is often not what others like.

Comment: @Amit Asking for `their views and will they recommend it` **is** asking for an opinion. It's basically the definition of opinion, which is why reviews are problematic.

Comment: Another point is that if any phone is recommended here, it can't stay for long. New phones are being launched every now and then, and none can be recommended for a long period of time. So, if the feature is introduced, it will have to be updated with each launch of a new phone, and that will be a major burden on the moderators. Why? "Seek happiness for others, and you'll be happy doing so. " - Me. :)