# Is there a place online for asking questions about old, pre-Android, non-smart phones?

Tags: discussion

Questions about non-Android phones are obviously off-topic here.  But where (if anywhere) are they *on*-topic?  Like, say someone has an old (still working) flip phone, and they want to ask questions about it.  Where on the internet should they go?

Comment: For a starter: [Where can I ask questions that aren't Android Enthusiast questions?](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/q/371/16575)

Comment: If you're looking for SE sites, then unfortunately [there's none](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/199623/241919). However, I'm not really sure either for general mobile phone discussion. Perhaps the best you can try is either their official forum or 3rd-party/community forum.